# Finding primeNumber and repDigit fails

Tags: java

I have a method for finding, wheter a number is a prime or not. It is working in my test class, but when I am using System.outprintf, it fails.
Same for the repDigit method.

Any help would be appreciated

Method for finding prime number:

```
/**
     * Checks whether the number is a prime number.
     *
     * @param number Any number
     * @return true if the number is prime, otherwise false
     */
    public static boolean isPrime(int number) {
        boolean isPrime = true;
        if (number < 2) {
            isPrime = false;
        } else {
            // Start counting from two to begin with even numbers
            for (int i = 2; i < number/2; ++i) {
                if (number % i == 0) {
                    isPrime = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return isPrime;
    }
```

Method for finding repDigit:

```
 /**
 * This method checks if numbers, after each other, are the same. We take
 * modulus of the number, in order to get the last digit, as long as the
 * number is above 0. The number is divided by 10, to end up with all
 * remaining numbers. Then it checks, if the last digit + the remaining are
 * the same
 *
 * @param number
 * @return
 */
public static boolean isRepDigit(int number) {
    int repDigit = number % 10;
    boolean toReturn = true;
    if (number < 10) {
        toReturn = false;
    } else {
        while (number > 0) {
            int digit = number % 10;
            number = number / 10;
            if (repDigit != digit) {
                toReturn = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return toReturn;
}
```

Main method:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int START = 5;
    final int END = 100;
    final int SPACE = digitCount(END);
    for (int i = START; i < END; i++) {

        System.out.printf("%" + SPACE + "d is a repdigit &n", isRepDigit(i));
        System.out.printf("%" + SPACE + "d is a prime &n", isPrime(i));
    }
}
```

Error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.Boolean
at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:4302)
at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printInteger(Formatter.java:2793)
at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2747)
at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2520)
at java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:970)
at java.io.PrintStream.printf(PrintStream.java:871)
at Grp17_ueb01.main(Grp17_ueb01.java:164)
C:\Users\rasmu\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ueb01\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1040: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\rasmu\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ueb01\nbproject\build-impl.xml:805: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

Comment: What is the actual error message and stacktrace that you get?

Comment: Provide question with the output(may be wrong) or the error you get

Comment: Just added it to the post

Comment: If you're using `printf` with booleans you need to use `%b` for the replacement

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstood the meaning of the second argument of `printf`.
Here `d` in your string is supposed to be replaced by as a decimal, given as second argument. And the boolean `isRepDigit(i)` cannot be converted as a decimal.

The printf method documentation may be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf-java.util.Locale-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-).

The Format string syntax is explained [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax).

What I think you wanted is:

```
    if (isRepDigit(i)) {
        System.out.printf("%" + SPACE + "d is a repdigit \n", i);
    }
    if (isPrime(i)) {
        System.out.printf("%" + SPACE + "d is a prime \n", i);
    }
```

Comment: Reaplacing the %d with %b prints out true or false, which is not what i want. I want to print the decimal, hence the %d.

Comment: In that case what I think you wanted is `System.out.printf("%" + SPACE + "d is a repdigit /n", i);`

Comment: Well, it sort of works. It prints al integers between 5 and 100.
But the idea is to only print out eg. 11, 22.

Comment: I've executed the code that can be found here: https://gist.github.com/x4d3/e5d4641d1e4a805653c60cd785376410 and I did observe the right behavior.

Comment: Ohh, I totally forgot to add if (isRepDigit(i)) to my code (Cannot figure out how to mark as code though). Sorry about the extra work. Thank youy very much.